# Steps to converting a LAN Chat to Internet Chat

Tags: java

At the moment I have a fully functional java multiClient chat program that works in a LAN environment, I would like to know the steps I need to take to get it to work over the internet in terms of port forwarding/ports, router config etc. - I really have no idea how to convert it to have internet capabilities.

= EDIT = 
forgot to mention that it uses basic java sockets and objectStreams to send a serialized class which is my 'packet'

Comment: Just port-forward and have the endpoints outside the LAN. This is system-specific, and requires few changes in the code. The TCP/IP protocols handle most of this for you.

Comment: Will definitely do the port forwarding, what do you mean by 'enpoints'?

Comment: Endpoints=client and server.